# After Effects - Expression result must be of dimension 2, not 1 - Why do I get this error when assign var t to Global time variable?

Tags: after-effects

Global variable time is a number, not array as I know. Why do I get this error at `t = time;`?

```
t = time;
finishTime = 0;
if(t >= 0.14 && finishTime != 0.7)
{
    loopOut("cycle");
    finishTime = time;
}
if(finishTime >= 0.7)
{
    finishTime = 0;
    t = 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Weird. Definitely typeof(time) returns NUMBER. Stunned

Answer (score 0):

Oh I think this does not refer to the time but to the property you are writing the expression. So for example, if you use this in a position without separating the dimensions first (hence a two dimension array) the error occurs. But if you separate the dimensions, the error does not occur. So apparently the variable "t" is seen in context with the property you are working in.